# Problem in partition mounting NTFS

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

where i click in open storage hd

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/.../HD: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/.../HD"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Comment: The issues could be different, or the steps to fix it could be different, he hasn't given us much information, so until then lets not mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Are you dualbooting Windows and Ubuntu? And which Windows? And is Windows installed on the HD you are trying to mount? If not, has windows access that HD before?

Comment: I agree with Muru: the 2 MFTs don't agree with one another. Duplicate.